# Gathering a collection of elements for a basic tab switcher

Tags: reactjs

### Objective

I want to make a basic tab switcher with React, starting with gathering a collection of tab elements.

### Error

The array of HTML elements I'm able to assemble after my code has run contains a number of null entries equal to that of the actual elements.

### Attempt

I have a wrapper for the entire structure, and here is its render method:

```
render(){
return (
    <section className={"TR-Resume " + this.state.closedClass} ref="resume">
        <div className={"TR-ResumeInner " + this.state.collapsedClass} ref="resumeInner">
            <header className="TR-ResumeHeader">
                <h2>Resumé</h2>
                <Link to="/" className="TR-ResumeClose" onClick={this.close.bind(this)}>&times;</Link>
            </header>
            <section className="TR-ResumeMain js-ResumeTabs" ref="resumeTabs">
                <header className="TR-ResumeTabs">
                    <Tabs className="js-Tabs" resume={this.props.resume.resume} tabRef={el => this.tabs.push(el)} />
                </header>
                <section className="TR-ResumeContent">
                    <Sections tabs={this.props.resume.resume} sectionRef={el => this.sections.push(el)} />
                </section>
            </section>
        </div>
    </section>
)
}
```

You'll notice I am using the [React recommended method](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components) of exposing refs of children components to parents. I am appending each to a property of the parent component: `tabRef={el => this.tabs.push(el)}`

I understand I am re-declaring that collection every time the  block renders, so to prevent appending the same elements to the collection, I'm clearing it in `componentWillUpdate()` lifecycle event:

```
componentWillUpdate() { 
this.tabs.length = 0;
}
```

### Result

My plan is to attach click events to the tabs to switch between panels, but I can't get that far, because by the time the `componentDidUpdate()` event fires, this is was is output in the array when I log it to the console:

```
[ null, null, null, null, a.TR-ResumeTab.js-Tab.TR-ResumeTab_active, a.TR-ResumeTab.js-Tab, a.TR-ResumeTab.js-Tab, a.TR-ResumeTab.js-Tab ]
```

Is there a better way to do this? Am I doing something wrong?

I plan to take these to animate tab panel with GSAP and want to avoid using jQuery.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with how you are using refs. When you do an inline ref declaration ( `ref={ref => this.input = ref}` ), the first time the component renders, it will receive a `null` value. Then on the second render, the refs will be correctly assigned. So that is why you first see the 4 `null` values, and then the 4 correct values.

To get around this, you should supply a class method to the `ref` prop instead of an inline function.

Example:

This:

```
render() {
    return (
        ...
        <Tabs className="js-Tabs" resume={this.props.resume.resume} tabRef={el => this.tabs.push(el)} />
        ...
    )
}
```

Should be:

```
applyRef = ref => {
    this.tabs.push(ref);
}
render() {
    return (
        ...
        <Tabs className="js-Tabs" resume={this.props.resume.resume} tabRef={this.applyRef} />
        ...
    )
}
```

When you use a class method to apply a ref, it only gets called once when the actual element has been added to the dom, so you shouldn't get the initial `null` values anymore.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you.
I should add that this solution also allowed me to get rid of the questionable "emptying out" of the array I was having to do on update.

Comment: Awesome glad you got it working! I learned about this the hard way, it's not well documented. I found out about the different behaviour through some github issues.

Comment: Yeah finding this solution was no easy find. Even finding a good search phrase to query for an answer was tough.